# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.transition.Fade cannot be cast to android.transition.Transition?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation

That exception was thrown when trying to add animations to replacing fragments.
According to this answer, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016278/how-to-use-android-support-transition-transition-transitionset-as-a-fragment-sha), the transition framework cannot be applied to fragments but this post shows you can [How to use Material Transitions in Fragment Transactions](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/how-to-use-material-transitions-in-fragment-transactions-5a62b9d0b26b) Code I tried is below

```
final JobFragment jobFragment = JobFragment.newInstance(job);
    final Fragment previousFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //exit transition
    Fade exitFade = new Fade();
    exitFade.setDuration(1000);
    previousFragment.setExitTransition(exitFade);
    //enter transition
    Explode enterExplode = new Explode();
    enterExplode.setDuration(1000);
    jobFragment.setEnterTransition(enterExplode);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, jobFragment).addToBackStack("jobDetails")
            .commit();
```

Comment: The answer is in your title - you have the wrong import, one is for support library, the other isn't.. Check you have consistent imports

Comment: That was it!! Thanks

Comment: @MarkKeen Do you want to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: If you are looking to support API 14+ use version 27.0.0 of the Support Library, which includes support for Support Library Transitions for fragments. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your title - you have the wrong import, one is for support library, the other isn't.. Check you have consistent imports.

Example:

```
import android.support.transition.Fade;
import android.support.transition.Transition;
```

or:

```
import android.transition.Fade;
import android.transition.Transition;
```

For compatibility use the `support` (added in 24.2.0) version.